# Multiple controller constructors when injecting dependencies using Unity.Mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm very new to dependency injection and I've just set up Unity.Mvc5 and has some success with it. But now I face the problem of multiple contructors in my controller class. I already have constructors that handle my `UserManager` and following tutorials I understand I need another constructor to instantiate my interface. When I do this however, I get the following error:

> The type OrganisationController has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.

A snippet from my controller:

```
    private IPush _pushMessage;

    // Here is the problem!
    public OrganisationController(IPush pushMessage)
    {
        _pushMessage = pushMessage;
    }

    public OrganisationController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public OrganisationController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyApp");
        UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("PasswordReset"));
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

And my `UnityConfig.cs` as follows:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IPush, PushMessage>();
        container.RegisterType<IController, OrganisationController>();
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to tell Unity that I have another constructor being used to implement an interface.

Comment: Try marking the ctor you want to use for DI with [InjectionConstructor] attribute. This will allow unity identify which ctor to resolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using DI, constructors are specifically *for* DI. There is no reason to create alternate constructors (especially on controllers, since the only caller is the `ControllerFactory` which delegates the call to the DI container).

In fact, [using multiple constructors with dependency injection is anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) and should be avoided.

Related: [Rebuttal: Constructor over-injection anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorover-injectionanti-pattern/)

Comment: Accepting this answer, not because it solves my exact problem but because it removes the root cause of my problem. I've removed the other constructors and instantiated UserManager elsewhere. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with other answer by @NightOwl888. In some cases you may want to have multiple constructors.

Have you tried InjectionConstructor attribute?

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public OrganisationController(IPush pushMessage)
{
    _pushMessage = pushMessage;
}
```

Comment: Does this need a neuget package?

Comment: yes, search for Unity.